# Serializing List<Item> to JSON with custom fields

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, gson

I'm trying to create a simple REST API with Spring MVC, that returns data in JSON format.

I'm working on a method that returns a list of authors, that's accessed from example.com/api/authors?find=somename

I have a JPA entity called Authors. I have a `@Service` that fetches a `List<Author>` collection. The `Author` entity has properties, like `id, firstName, lastName, birthDate`.

What I'm trying to achieve is that my JSON result is something like:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Leo Tolstoi",
            "age": 49
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Billy Shakespeare",
            "age": 32
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the result has 2 fields that are not directly from the entity, rather should be generated from `Author` entity's values. The `name` field is `author.getFirstName() + " " + author.getLastName()` and the `age` is `someUtilityClass.calcAge(author.getBirthDate())`

I'm trying to figure out how to get this sort of output using GSON.

What I could do, is fetch data from the service class and iterate over it, saving each iteration row to a Map (or something, maybe just save each row to something like `List<AuthorJson>` entity, which has fields like `id, name, age`). But this approach doesn't seem to be very clean.

Can you guys suggest any solutions?

Comment: The DTO approach is appropriate. Otherwise use a `TypeAdapter` but in that case you're putting business logic in serializers and that doesn't make sense, imo.

Comment: What would be the good approach then? Converting database results 1:1 to JSON is a very bad idea. It can break the client's application because the field names might fluctuate. And database may hold values that are not fit for public exposure. E.g. password hashes, personal information etc.

Comment: Write a DTO converter and serialize the resulting DTO.

Comment: So go with my initial approach? I looked up what DTO means, and it seems like my proposed AuthorJson entity is just that. It holds the properties needed to return for given result.

Comment: That's how I would do it.

Comment: Create Maps with id/name/age, put them into a List, put the list into a Map under the name "data", serialize the whole thing.  It's done faster than you can describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom Serializer for Author.

[Documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)

Since you just need a Serializer, here is an example of what you can do. Note that age will be off by one most of the time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GsonBuilder gBuild = new GsonBuilder();
    gBuild.registerTypeAdapter(Author.class, new AuthorSerializer());

    Author author = new Author();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1988);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    author.setBirthDate(cal);
    author.setFirstName("John");
    author.setLastName("Smith");

    Gson gson = gBuild.setPrettyPrinting().create();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(author));
}

private static class AuthorSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Author> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Author src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - src.getBirthDate().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String fullName = src.getFirstName() + " " + src.getLastName();
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.addProperty("fullName", fullName);
        obj.addProperty("age", age);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: but I don't need to de-serialize my own JSON output, it's made for consumption

Comment: Then you should be fine just making just a serialier. Usually you make both a serialier and deserializers. Internally, GSON might need a deserializer or instance creators.